# Trouble with adding percentages to stretch fully

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get a ul with different coloured inner elements to equally stretch 100%. It's fine until I test under 1280px. I have to minimize the window still to see it and also intermittent so tough to catch. Everything adds up. I really don't know what wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

http://codepen.io/Compton/pen/xdGpm/

```
<div id="colour-bar">
<ul>
 <li class="orange"></li>
 <li class="spacer"></li>
 <li class="red"></li>
 <li class="spacer"></li>
 <li class="pink"></li>
 <li class="spacer"></li>
 <li class="purple"></li>
 <li class="spacer"></li>
 <li class="blue"></li>
 <li class="spacer"></li>
 <li class="green"></li>
 <li class="spacer"></li>
 <li class="yellow"></li>
</ul>
</div>

.orange {
    background-color:#f37028;
}

.red {
    background-color:#ed1b24;
}

.pink {
    background-color:#e54198;
}

.purple {
    background-color:#6b439c;
}

.blue {
    background-color:#0193cf;
}

.green {
    background-color:#91ff01;
}

.yellow {
    background-color:#fff300;
}

#colour-bar {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    height:10px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#colour-bar ul {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#colour-bar ul li {
    width:14.24%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}

#colour-bar ul li.spacer {  
   width:0.05333%;
   height:100%;
   display:block;
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue probably occurs due to some rounding inaccuracies that every browser introduces at some viewport widths, therefore sometimes the space between items disappear.

Furthermore, your spacer elements have a width of `0.0533%` of the available width, so this means that the space is exactly `1px` when the container is at least  `1876px` wide: below of this width is a choice of the browser how to round the value

Try this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ioxtE

I first suggest to remove all the `spacer` elements (since it is empty markup, only for styling purpose, thus is a bad practice)

```
<div id="colour-bar">
 <ul>
   <li class="orange"></li>
   <li class="red"></li>
   <li class="pink"></li>
   <li class="purple"></li>
   <li class="blue"></li>
   <li class="green"></li>
   <li class="yellow"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

then give a space between list-items with

```
#colour-bar li + li {
  border-left: 1px #fff solid;
}
```

and assign this style

```
#colour-bar ul li {
   width:14.275%;   /*  ~(100/7)  */
   ...
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and the space between colours is always in its place

Comment: I have to rework a couple elements of my page but this worked fantastically. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it's width to the viewport width, first add the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

and then give the div the viewport width instead of percentage:

```
#colour-bar {
top:0;
left:0;
width:100vw;
position:fixed;
height:10px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't seem to help. I'm currently testing for laptop and initially at full scale it works fine but when I bring the width of the window down to spacers seem to collapse at certain spots. If I bring it down more, it looks like it's collapsing at different spots.